# Cron Job - Pure Django project with google app engine

Tags: django, google-app-engine, cron

I know how to setup cron job in django and app engine , but how can i setup cron job in app engine with pure django project. Any guidance ? Thanks.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. You say you know how to set up a cron job, then ask how to set up a cron job. What, exactly, are you having trouble with?

Comment: I want to setup cron job in app engine with pure django project. How can i do that ?

Comment: Yes, I saw that from the question. What is a "pure Django project" and how is it different from the thing you say you already know how to do?

Comment: I know how to setup cron job in django using custom management command , and put the command in crontab. crontab will execute my job many times. My question is that when i upload my app engine project [ with pure django code] to appspot.com , the crontab will not be available for me. Then how can i setup cron job ?

Answer (score 0):

See: [Scheduled Tasks with Cron for Python](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron)

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible as `GAE Cron Job` uses `HTTP` and `Django` uses `HTTPS`. When `Cron job` sends a request, it expects `HTTP 200` in response and gets `HTTP 301` instead, as Your `Django` redirects non-secured requests to `HTTPS`.
There are five options:

1. Lower the security level of Your `Django` app to `HTTP` (not recommended)
2. Create an `HTTP>HTTPS` proxy app on GAE and direct Your cron there
3. Create a cron app on `GAE/GKE` and use it
4. Try to setup Celery, using `GAE/GKE` and forget about cron
5. Change cloud platform provider to something more convenient

Update: There is one trick with cron jobs, I've just found. You can use Cloud Scheduler and setup HTTPS link to You project by choosing HTTP as a target (not App Engine HTTP!). In such way You will get the desired result.

Comment: Update Feb 2021: You can keep using HTTPS for all other urls, but specifically allow HTTP for cron urls, assuming they start with 'cron'. SECURE_REDIRECT_EXEMPT = ['cron/.*']